# Fun Rails ActiveRecord Join with attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm feeling rusty on my basic rails and working on a simple music stats service.

```
class User
  has_many :monthly_top_artists # this model also has play_count and month attrs- not just a join
  has_many :top_artists, through: monthly_top_artists, source: :artist
```

I've basically written my own `#monthly_top_artists` query method which queries for a specific month's artists. right now i'm working with a line like this:

```
current_top_artists = MonthlyTopArtist.where(user_id: id, month: time_range)
  .joins(:artist).select('month,name,play_count,user_id,artist_id,monthly_top_artists.updated_at')
```

The purpose of this is to load up my MonthlyTopArtist model with all the artist data as well- but am I just forgetting some basic rails/active record methods that can handle this for me? I could also use `user.top_artists` with the code above, but this would give me the same problem- the monthly statistics are in another table. Am I overthinking this in trying to limit my db queries? I realize that writing my own getter method is a little bit more than vanilla rails but this join + selecting attributes not defined on my MTA model is making me think there is something bigger wrong with my schema (or i'm just forgetting something).

Comment: If all you're doing is getting all the fields for a top-artist, then you shouldn't need the select, just use `all` or `each` on the returned active record collection (as appropriate). If you want to filter out some of the fields, then you need select.

Comment: I think my concern is both that and whether I'm conflating active record associations with this join table. I want attributes from both tables in my model, but I'm naming my getter method like it is a simple AR association. This would be fine and automatic if I were treating MTA like a user's favorites, but there is additional information that I'm trying to merge into a new logical model.

Comment: Can you do what you need with includes? eg `user.top_artists.include(:monthly_top_artist)` or similar?